# How to avoid locking UI when error logging in?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a simple login/create user script. The problem is that whenever I log in unsuccessfully, the script freezes. Any idea how to fix this?

```
public void LoginButtonPressed()
{
    FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(EmailAddress.text, Password.text).
        ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            if (task.IsCanceled)
            {
                Debug.LogError("Login was canceled");
                userText = "2";
            }

            if(task.IsFaulted)
            {
                Debug.LogError("Error logging in");
                userText = "3";
            }

            if(task.IsCompleted)
            {
                Debug.LogFormat("Usermanager: User signed in successfully: {0}", EmailAddress.text);
                userText = "4";
                isLoadMainScene = true;
            }
        });
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does "Error logging in" print?

Comment: Yes it does, the logs work fine, but the UI itself gets stuck.

Comment: Do you mean that only the login button does not respond? Or do none of the elements on it respond?  Could you please edit your question to include an image of the inspector view of your ui, as well as an image of the ui's hierarchy?

Comment: None of the elements respond as soon as the failed login attempt happens. I updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you found an answer there are things you should know about logging:

`Debug.Log` is used to create a log *without pausing.*

`Debug.LogWarning` is used to create a warning massage *without pausing.*

`Debug.LogError` is used to create an error message *with the ability to pause the code execution.*

---

> How to avoid locking UI when error logging in?

The pausing feature should **not** prevent you from using `Debug.LogError`. It is very helpful because it allows you to pause the code when you see the log in the Editor. If you want your log to be marked as "error", you can still use `Debug.LogError` and avoid this pausing when using `Debug.LogError` by disabling the "Error Pause" option in the Console tab.

[image]

See, the image above, it is enabled. Just click on "Error Pause" once to disable it.

Answer (score 3):

Using `Debug.LogError(String)` causes it to end the script.

Instead, use `Debug.Log(String);` to log messages and continue executing.

Comment: This is assuming we talk about a build not the Editor. But I would assume the same ;)